# Se requiere listar los articulos que hayan sido vendidos "A TODOS" los clientes

Tags: mysql

Intenté esta consulta-subconsulta

1. obtener la cantidad de clientes para saber cuantos son "todos los clientes". OK
2. obtener la cantidad de clientes a los que se les vendió el articulo. OK
3. entonces si el total de clientes (2) es igual a la cantidad de clientes a los que se les vendió un articulo (1), debe aparecer en la consulta. PROBLEMA CON ESTO no supe como usar estos valores en una claúsula where. Y no sé si estoy planteando la consulta-subconsulta correctamente.

TABLE **articulos**
art_cod char
art_desc varchar
primary key(art_cod)

TABLE **clientes**
clie_cod
clie_razon
primary key(clie_cod)

TABLE **facturas_cab**
fc_nro
fc_fecha
clie_cod
fc_monto
primary key(fc_nro)

TABLE **facturas_det**
fc_nro
art_cod
fd_cant
fd_art_precio
primary key (fc_nro, art_cod)

```
select **det.art_cod** , 
       **@a:=count(fac.clie_cod)** , 
       **@b:=(select count(*) from clientes)** 
from facturas_det as det
join facturas_cab as fac on fac.fc_nro = det.fc_nro
where @a = @b ---> "no funciona y no se como establecer la condicion que funcione"   
group by det.art_cod
```

SOLUCION a listar los artículos que hayan sido vendidos "a todos" los clientes

```
select artVendido, cantClientesVendido, totClientes from 
( select det.art_cod as artVendido, 
       count(fac.clie_cod) as cantClientesVendido, 
       (select count(*) from clientes) as totClientes 
  from facturas_det as det
  join facturas_cab as fac on fac.fc_pto_vta = det.fc_pto_vta and fac.fc_nro = det.fc_nro
  group by det.art_cod
) as origen
where cantClientesVendido = totClientes
;
```

Comment: hola! bienvenidx a SOes. Te faltó decirnos cuál es tu pregunta.

Comment: Disculpas. Mi pregunta era como puedo hacer para listar los articulos que se le hayan vendido "a todos" los clientes.
Ya lo resolvi con la ayuda de otra colega.

Dejo la solucion para a quien le pueda ser util
Gracias por responder

Comment: Ponlo abajo como respuesta. Incluso podrás marcarla como respuesta aceptada, así otros sabrán que encontraste la solución. Recibirás votos positivos y tal